# Is it possible to trigger a haptic feedback without the accompanying sound on apple Watch OS 2

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, haptic-feedback

Assuming the user has not muted their watch sounds.  Is it possible for an apple watch app to trigger a haptic feedback (i.e vibrate) without the accompanying sound.

This is different than receiving a notification which is handled automatically by the watch.  In this case I'm invoking the haptic feedback using a watch app.

like this:
    [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticTypeClick];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local notification only vibrate the apple watch and not play a sound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863755/can-a-local-notification-only-vibrate-the-apple-watch-and-not-play-a-sound)

Comment: That's my question as well. Neither has an answer. They are different questions. In this one I'm trying to see if I invoke it specifically if there is a way to suppress the sound. The other relates to how the watch handles notifications in general and if there is a way for the notifier to suppress the sound.

Answer (score 4):

There is a hacky way to do so. You can start to play `WKAudioFilePlayer` right before haptic and there will be no sound:

```
player.play()
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.click)
```

I suggest you to create a short silent (very low amplitude and high pitch) audio file for this purpose. And remember that this solution can be buggy.

Comment: Hi @kelin, any update doing this with AVPlayer as WKAudioFilePlayer was depracated? When I play AVPlayer right before haptic feedback, it is being ignored at all. Thanks a lot for any hint how to make it work thanks!