# Apple Watch silent haptic feedback or custom vibration

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

The idea is to play haptic feedback without any sound even if device's sound is turned on. I've tried to play music, video on device but haptic's sound only became quieter.
Maybe I can create custom haptic feedback but I couldn't find the way to do it.
Any solutions?

Guys from this app did it
https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id320606217

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to trigger a haptic feedback without the accompanying sound on apple Watch OS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885193/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-haptic-feedback-without-the-accompanying-sound-on-ap)

Answer (score 0):

Silent haptic feedback when the system sound is on and custom haptics are not possible for watchOS developers at the current time, and there are no workarounds. I suggest filing a report in Bug Reporter (https://bugreport.apple.com/web/).