# Watchkit: How do you call for a vibrate without sound?

Tags: xcode, watchkit, haptic-feedback

In WatchKit, I call:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.start)
```

... and the watch vibrates - but *also has a sound*.

What do I call to vibrate the watch *without* a sound?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to trigger a haptic feedback without the accompanying sound on apple Watch OS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885193/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-haptic-feedback-without-the-accompanying-sound-on-ap)

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t possible, the user has to turn on silent mode themselves from Control Center in watchOS.